# Group rows by field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

```
+------------------------+
| id |  name  | category |
+------------------------+
|  1 | name_1 |    cat_1 |
|  2 | name_2 |    cat_2 |
|  3 | name_3 |    cat_1 |
|  . |   .    |      .   |
|  . |   .    |      .   |
|  n | name_n |    cat_k |
+------------------------+
```

were "n" is the total rows of table and "k" is an arbitrary number. My question is, is there any way to make an SQL query that retrieve rows grouped by category? I mean it is possible to get something like this structure?

```
array(
    "cat_1" => array(
                     "name_1", "1",
                     "name_3", "3",
               ),
    "cat_2" => array(
                     "name_2", "2",
                      some rows ....
               ),
    ...
    "cat_k" => array(
                     some rows....
               ),
)
```

If there is any way please give me some keywords, not entire solution please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this in a single query since mysql alone will not be able to yield multi-dimensional arrays, but it's almost trivial to do using PHP.  Basically here is what you would do:

```
$cats = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($cats[$row->category])) {
        $cats[$row->category] = array();
    }
    $cats[$row->category][] = $row->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The query itself will not give you that structure, but it is quite easy to read the result set into that sort of two dimensional array:

```
$query = "SELECT category, id, name FROM table ORDER BY category ASC, id ASC";


$result = /* use you DB query mechanism of choice here */;

$array = array();

while($row = /* use your DB row fetch mechanism of choice here */) {
    $array[$row['category']][] = array($row['id'] => $row['name']);
}
```

Comment: what about using GROUP_CONCAT and then explode every element of the result? wich one is more efficient?

Comment: @papelucho That would require you to do GROUP_CONCAT on both id and name fields, so you would have two fields to explode and populate. On the other hand, you would have fewer rows in the result set to iterate through.  I can't speak to which one would be more operationally efficient (you could test this), I can however say that it would be very unconventional to do this using GROUP_CONCAT.  The approach I have suggested would also be much easier to work with if you needed to get data across a JOIN (for example maybe a category description field from another table).